# Does memory allocation for a View depend on its dimensions?

Tags: android, view

I'm planning to implement a very large view (i.e. much larger than a typical screen size) and want to ensure that the View implementation will not allocate some Bitmap or other buffer that is huge, proportional to the View dimensions.

I might be able to use a ListView for one of the dimensions, but not the other (still thinking through the design).  I have ideas on how to avoid a large memory consumption issue but before coding would like to know if that is even an issue; it's probably simpler to just define the View for the dimensions I want.

I may write a program to report memory usage when allocating different sized views but am concerned that my code might not report the correct figures since there are many conditions that could give me false results.  For example, which memory stat do I retrieve?  Or does it matter whether the view has child views or not?

I'm hoping someone has a quick answer.  Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html this link explores some options

Comment: An easy way to check would to simply create a stupidly large view (larger than the one you intend to create) and watch for OOM errors in the stack trace. While this may not be the most accurate way to test, this can give you a insight to the different points of failure that may occur with large views.

Comment: Conceptually that would be easy.  But as I wrote above, it could easily be misleading.  For example, the View might allocate a large chunk during rendering and then release it.  Checking before and after would, then, report roughly 0 memory usage.

Comment: @illegal-argument The "tracking allocations" might work.  It seems that if a large chunk(s) are allocated, they should show up in the tracking.  Thanks.

Comment: @PeriHartman My point was to create such a large view that the view creation/rendering crashes the app. Then you can use the stack trace to figure out the reason for the crash to see if its memory-related. At the same time, if creating a stupidly large view does not crash your program you can be pretty sure that high memory allocations aren't going to be of concern (as the system itself probably wouldn't have the memory required to contain such a large buffer, suggesting that it probably isn't allocating view-sized buffers).

Comment: @PeriHartman I think this is the most accurate way of knowing https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#ViewingAllocations especially PSS measurement is notable and google provided gmail sample data

Comment: I think I have a partial conclusion.  I will likely need to use onDraw or dispatchDraw.  Either one takes a canvas with a buffer of the size of the view.  Therefore I will want a relatively small view.  Agreed?